# Saving User Input by taking care of security as well

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Following is my script which I am usng to make insertion in my database. I didn't use `stripslashes or mysqli_escape` because I read that when you are using prepared statement we don't need to use that. The issue I am facing is that will the following method is good in terms of security and whenever I make insertion then for special characters garbage text got stored in my database like following example. Kindly let me know how can I modify the query so it stores the values as they are being saved by user. Thanks,

`You shouldnÃ¢â‚¬â„¢t move them to the next level of delegation.`

```
    $storeit = $_POST['value'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO db_table  (thevalue) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $storeit); /// s means only string input is allowed

    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
    echo "true";
    }
    else
    echo "false".$stmt->error;
```

Comment: s means *any* input is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `$con->set_charset()` after connect, and pass the actual encoding of the web page, i.e.:

```
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

if your page is sending utf-8 as content charset.

Comment: Hey my issue has nothing to do wih the encoding right? html* php functions are helpful to this or the solution you mentioned is generic?

Comment: Hey I was also looking at your AWESOME script. Kindly let me know where can I find its documentation - https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql 

Also can I bind with your library queries like `select ? from ?` because I cannot with  current paramaterized query with your library

Comment: yes you can. you have to use `?n` placeholder for the table and field names. However, you have to be careful with this kind of queries - with such a query you will let a hacker to view any table in your base/ So, it's better to hardcode table names

Comment: documentation is scarse, mostly written as comments in the code

Comment: I am really liking your library. Thanks for making such thing for us (especially rookies like me :) That way we can take care of security our self as well. ). Kindly let me know one last thing my current issue has nothing to do with the encoding right? html* php functions are helpful to this or the solution you mentioned is generic?

Comment: I wouldn't write my answer if it had nothing to do. When you see a spoiled text - it's nothing but encoding

Comment: Oh I got it wrong then I though html* functions does the encoding. But now its clear `$con->set_charset('utf8');` does the encoding as well. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seem to be related to encoding.

Be sure that you have the same encoding in:

- database
- table
- database connection
- user data (html form)
- php file itself when stored

About the input data, you can check and/or adjust the data to whichever character set you want to use. You can check the [Multibyte String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions or the [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) functions.

Comment: Why should one have the same encoding on the table and database?

Comment: It's not needed at all. But when somebody has encoding problems, it's usually easiest to check that all are using the same. Usually, not always, if somebody needs a different encoding on a table, knows what is doing and knows how to do the changes, what and where to set it.

Comment: It is easiest way to check NOTHING. Either if table and DB encoding are the same, or if they are different - it doesn't matter even a little - so, there is no point to check it. As well as encoding of PHP file.

Comment: Well, I disagree, based on my personal experience, not to mention others, but it seems that we are not going to agree, so I'll stop here.

Comment: It is not about "personal experience" but rather FACTS. Database encoding never interfere with existing tables encoding, and used only as a default with creation of new ones. Facts don't need to be agreed or disagreed with - they are remains the same despite of some ones opinion